# 3x3x3 LED cube with Raspberry Pi GPIO, Python script not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

I am making a 3x3x3 LED cube and I am trying to control it with a Raspberry Pi. I found a script that should work for it but I get this error (to start off with):

```
sudo python led.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "led.py", line 9, in <module>
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setmode'
```

The code is almost 800 lines, so I won't put it here. You can download it from google docs: [wave.py](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByzG2Ps_dpjcNURWUVVITkFCODA/edit)

This is the first nine lines though:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/env/python3.2
2 # 3x3 LED Cube
3 # Position 11 - 33 are connected to LED Cathode (-)
4 # Layers are connected to LED Anode (+)
5 
6 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
7 from time import sleep
8 
9 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
```

**Edit:**
Now I ran it as root and got a new error:

```
File "led.py", line 382
i = 0
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: weird, does `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` work ? If you do `dir(GPIO)` do you see the BOARD constant listed ?

Comment: GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) didn't work and when i did dir(GPIO) i got a syntax error: Syntax error near unexpected token 'GPIO'

Comment: I added a a new error to the question, please help

Comment: Weird...ok, let's start from scartch: step by step. First create a new python script, just add the import (`import RPi.GPIO as GPIO`) and run it as root. If this doesn't work, for some reason the RPi.GPIO package is missing on your Python install. Are you using Raspian ? If so, try this in Terminal: `sudo apt-get update` (this might be slow if you're not using the latest version
`sudo apt-get install python-dev` then
`sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio`. Hopefully the RPi.GPIO module should now be installed and the previous import script should work. Let me know

Comment: I made myself a new script from scratch, thanks though :)